# Yarn command gives error ..\..\package.json: Name contains illegal characters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarn-lock.json

Here is what my code looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5uqO.png)

First and foremost,i'm new to react.js and i'm just learning about yarn and I notice no matter which follow along I watch their react-app always gets a yarn.lock file and mine never does. Currently I'm using yarn version 1.22.19, node version 14.20.1(someone suggested that but no matter which version of node I switch too newer or older it doesn't help), and npm version 6.14.17.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `"name": "personal_portfolio_3"` to `"name": "personal-portfolio-3"`

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I actually had it as "personal-portfolio-3" prior to changing it to "personal_portfolio_3". This error actually just started happening earlier this week. It didn't happen on A different tutorial I followed last week.

Comment: I figured it out. After looking at the path and the error it was the space between "My PC" that was actually giving me that error so I put it in my project folder instead the "My PC" folder instead and that worked. So instead the path now looks like C:\Users\Public\name_of_app> Instead of C:\Users\My PC\name_of_app>. Thanks again.